# The diagonalizable matrices are not dense in the square real matrices

Tags: general-topology, matrices, diagonalization

Suppose that $n \ge 2$. How to prove that the set $\mathcal D \subset M_n(\mathbb R)$ of the diagonalizable real matrices is not dense in $M_n(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: Can you find a non-zero linear functional which vanishes on diagonal matrices? Then, we can use Hahn-Banach theorem  to conclude non-density.

Comment: @Nitrogen $\mathcal D$ is **not** a closet subset. The sequence of diagonalizable matrices $A_n\begin{pmatrix} 1 - 1/n & 1\\ 0 & 1+1/n\end{pmatrix}$ converges to a non diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Such a linear functional can't exist.

Comment: But it must, right? If you take the closure of the diagonalizable matrices, then this won't be the entire space, so you can apply Hahn-Banach, I think. (I could still be wrong, but I certainly think it applies in this context).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг If a non-zero linear functional which vanishes on diagonal matrices would exist, $\mathcal D$ would be included in an hyperplane. And this is not the case.

Comment: Yes, what you say is correct. But then, if the closure isn't dense, then Hahn-Banach theorem would  say the exact opposite of what you are implying, so I would love to know where I'm going wrong in this thinking, because I know I am.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $\mathcal D$ is not convex.

Comment: AHA! I just realized  that before your reply. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the matrix :

$$R=\pmatrix{0 & -1\cr 1 & 0}\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$$

which is *not* diagonalizable since its characteristic polynomial $X^2+1$ does not split in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Suppose there exists a sequence $(D_n)$ of diagonalizable matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$, which converges to $R$.

For every $n$, the characteristic polynomial of $D_n$ has nonnegative discriminant and by continuity of the determinant, it should be the same for $R$, but this is not the case.

This proves that the set $\mathcal{D}_2$ of all diagonalizable matrices in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is *not* dense in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Merci! Qu'est-ce qui t'a fait penser à utiliser le discriminant?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: Le discriminant donne un moyen naturel de savoir si un trinôme est scindé. Si une suite de matrices réelles dont les polynômes caractéristiques sont tous scindés dans $\mathbb{R}[X]$ converge, sa limite limite possède ainsi la même propriété (en taille $n\ge2$ quelconque, on peut utiliser le même outil : le discriminant d'un polynôme $P$ est le résultant de $P$ et de $P'$). D'où l'idée d'aller chercher une matrice réelle dont le polynôme caractéristique n'est *pas* scindé dans $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: $R$ does have nonnegative determinant, right?