# Is the set of $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrices with real entries dense in $M_n(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

We can prove that diagonalizable matrices with complex values are dense in set of $n \times n$ complex matrices, [as it was previously answered.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107945/diagonalizable-matrices-with-complex-values-are-dense-in-set-of-n-times-n-comp)

I don't think there is many chances but can we show that the set of diagonalizable matrices over $\mathbb R$ with real entries is dense in $M_n(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: This help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184461/the-diagonalizable-matrices-are-not-dense-in-the-square-real-matrices

Comment: I believe a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^2$ namely $((0,1),(-1,0))$ can not be approximated by diagonal matrices, since it has eigenvalue $i$.