# If diagonalizable matrices are not dense over $\Bbb R$, how common are they?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, diagonalization

The link: [The diagonalizable matrices are not dense in the square real matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184461/the-diagonalizable-matrices-are-not-dense-in-the-square-real-matrices) says that diagonalizable matrices are dense over $\Bbb C$ but not over $\Bbb R$. If that's the case, then the logical question is, what percentage of matrices over $\Bbb R$ are diagonalizable? The answer is going to be "it depends", so let's make it concrete. We pick each element of an $n \times n$ matrix from i.i.d uniform distributions over $[-1,1]$. What is the chance we'll get a diagonalizable matrix (over the reals)?

Comment: Think of this as how the set of $a$ such that the equation $x^2 = a$ has a solution is not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: In addition to measuring the size of the set of diagonalizable matrices, it might also be enlightening to figure out its shape or topological structure.

Comment: @Karl: Here there is a condition that all entries are in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Trebor - $x^2=a$ has a solution is dense in $\Bbb R$ right? Any $a$ in $[0,\infty)$ will work? And the set of $a$'s such that it doesn't have a solution is non-existent in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Let's take $n=2$ for simplicity. The matrix will not be diagonalizable over reals when it has complex eigenvalues (or repeated real ones with a single eigenvector, but the share of those is zero). That means that the characteristic equation has negative discriminant, i.e. $(\textrm{tr} A)^2-4\,\textrm{det} A =(a+d)^2 - 4\,(ad-bc)<0$. Now you need to find the 4D volume of that intersected with the 4D hypercube and divide it by the volume of the hypercube $2^4$. Use Maple or Mathematica if you really want to get the number.

Comment: @Conifold: This approach will not work probably for $n=3$ and certainly for $n=15$.

Comment: @markvs Exactly.

Comment: @Conifold: So what is the purpose of your comment? It does not help the OP. The case $n=2$ is easy, $n=1$ is even easier.

Comment: That it is not a very illuminating way of understanding the set of non-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: @Conifold:If there was a clear procedure for arbitrary $n$ as for $n=2$, that would be excellent. Your argument does not show that the procedure does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For a $2×2$ matrix, I think it is $49/72$.  You want real eigenvalues.
$$(\lambda-a)(\lambda-d)-bc=0\\
\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0\\
(a-d)^2+4bc\gt0$$
For set values of $a$ and $d$, the values of $b$ and $c$ are bounded by a hyperbola.  The area within the square $-1\lt b,c\lt1$ is
$$2+(a-d)^2/2-(a-d)^2\ln(|a-d|/2)$$
Integrate that over the region $-1\lt d\lt a\lt 1$.  Divide by $8$ which is the total volume integrated over, half of $[-1,1]^4$, and the result is $49/72$.
I suppose the fraction is less for larger matrices.  The proportion for a million $3×3$ was about $13/40$ and for a million $4×4$ was about $0.1080$

Comment: So it seems like if you increase $n$, most matrices are not diagonalizable?

Comment: There is more chance to get complex eigenvalues.  If you look up https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law,  most of the eigenvalues will usually be complex when $n$ is large.